# Simple micro framework for CRUD DB editing (PHP preferred)

Tags: php, framework, sqlite

I'm looking for the a very simple micro framework or similar free tool to make administrating an SQLite DB easier.
Something like SQL views, but more powerful. 
So basically an admin interface.

The reason is that the DB has multiple normalized tables that are not suited to manual editing, and I have plans to expand the DB.

It would be used locally, so no security or user model is needed.
The main requirement would be to minimize development time.

I did some work with Laravel a few years back (mostly forgotten now), while I liked the scaffolding and CRUD, it seems overkill for what I need now.

I prefer PHP, but JS is fine (and Perl :).

Currently I'm looking at a couple of Laravel generators: Craftable, Infyom Laravel Generator.
phpGrid seems like it could do the trick but it's not free.

Comment: https://www.phpliteadmin.org/ If not suitable, please update your question to give more requirements

Comment: I've updated the question. phplite or similar are not suitable. I'm already using a local SQLite browser.

Comment: I hope that you get an answer. The more detail you give us, the better the answers, generally speaking (GIGO). Good luck